# Yield a sequence of tuples instead of map

Tags: scala, dictionary, tuples

This is my code. To my surprise, it yields a map instead of a seq of tuples as I expect. What is right way to get list of tuples in scala?

```
for ((_, s) <- Constants.sites;
         line <- Source.fromFile(s"data/keywords/topkey$s.txt").getLines
    ) yield ((s, line))
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason probably is that `Constants.sites` is a `Map`, therefore it returns a map.

Instead of running the comprehension over `Constants.sites`, run it over `Constants.sites.values`, you are only using the values anyway.

The background is that your code gets translated to:

```
Constants.sites.flatMap {
  case (_, s) =>
    Source.fromFile(s"data/keywords/topkey$s.txt").getLines.map {
       line =>
         (s, line)
    }
}
```

And when calling `flatMap` on `Map` your resulting type also needs to be a `Map`, and the tuples can be coerced to a `Map`.

**EDIT:** But using this should be fine:

```
for {
  (_, s) <- Constants.sites
  line <- Source.fromFile(s"data/keywords/topkey$s.txt").getLines
) yield ((s, line))
```

Comment: Thanks for the refactored code. I tried it and found that flatMap still did not work as I expected. However, if we changed the flatMap to map{}.flatten then we will see the flatten Seq of tuple2s.

Comment: @HuCao wait, updated my post. The `flatMap` and `map` stuff is what Scala de-sugars the `for` to.

Comment: "The reason probably is that Constants.sites is a Map, therefore it returns a map." +1

Answer (score 0):

You could convert any Map to a Seq like this:

```
scala> val m = Map(1->"one", 2 -> "two")
m: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,String] = Map(1 -> one, 2 -> two)

scala> m.toSeq
res0: Seq[(Int, String)] = ArrayBuffer((1,one), (2,two))
```

In your case you might do

```
val result = for ((_, s) <- Constants.sites;
         line <- Source.fromFile(s"data/keywords/topkey$s.txt").getLines
    ) yield ((s, line))
result.toSeq
```