# Why for-loop with yield accumulates into a Map instead of a List?

Tags: scala, scala-collections, for-comprehension

I have the following code:

```
val dummy = Map(1 -> Map(2 -> 3.0,
                         4 -> 5.0),
                6 -> Map(7 -> 8.0))

val thisIsList = for (x <- dummy; y <- x._2.keys) yield s"(${x._1}, ${y})"
println(thisIsList)  // List((1, 2), (1, 4), (6, 7))

val thisIsMap = for (x <- dummy; y <- x._2.keys) yield new Tuple2(x._1, y)
println(thisIsMap)   // Map(1 -> 4, 6 -> 7) - this is not what I want
```

I would expect the second statement to produce a list of tuples, but instead it returns a Map.
I found an explanation here [scala: yield a sequence of tuples instead of map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30807104/scala-yield-a-sequence-of-tuples-instead-of-map) on why Map is returned, but I'm still struggling to find an elegant way to return a list of tuples instead in this case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because of how the `for` comprehension syntax is transformed by the compiler into a series of method calls. `map`, `flatMap`, and `withFilter` are targeted by the permutations of `for` comprehensions. This is very powerful and general because it allows  the syntax to work with arbitrary types.  There's more to this, such as the `CanBuildFrom`  implicit, but essentially mapping a `Map` to an `Iterable[Tuple[A, B]]` produces a `Map[A, B]`. [The signature is actually overloaded for `Map` to provide this behavior](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/Map.html#flatMap[K2,V2](f:((K,V))=>scala.collection.IterableOnce[(K2,V2)]):CC[K2,V2])

Specifically, given your original code below

```
val thisIsMap = for (x <- dummy; y <- x._2.keys) yield new Tuple2(x._1, y)
println(thisIsMap)   // Map(1 -> 4, 6 -> 7) - this is not what I want
```

The translation looks roughly like this

```
val thisIsMap = dummy.flatMap { x =>
  x._2.keys.map { y =>
    (x._1, y)
  }
}
```

See this [fiddle](https://scalafiddle.io/sf/CRH8qdF/3)

In order to obtain a list as desired, we can write

```
val thisIsMap = (for (x <- dummy; y <- x._2.keys) yield (x._1, y)).toList
```

However, if we consider what we've learned about `for` comprehensions, we can write it more elegantly as

```
val thisIsMap = for (x <- dummy.toList; y <- x._2.keys) yield (x._1, y)
```

In the above, we have leveraged the very behavior that confounded the original code by inferring that a `for` comprehension over a `List` will produce a `List`.

***However***, note the difference between converting the source into a `List` as opposed to converting the resulting map into a `List` after the comprehension.

If we call `toList` on the source (`dummy`) we get `List((1,2), (1,4), (6,7))` while if we call it on the result, we get `List((1,4), (6,7))`, for self evident reasons so choose carefully and deliberately.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
dummy
  .view
  .mapValues(_.keys.toList)
  .flatMap { case (key: Int, values: List[Int]) => values.map((key, _)) }
  .toList
```

which outputs

```
res0: List[(Int, Int)] = List((1,2), (1,4), (6,7)
```

Answer (score 0):

After working through the answers, will post a TLDR summary to my own question here.

The type of the data structure which is returned back by the *for* comprehension loop is expected to be the same, as the type which the *for* loop starts iterating over.
I.e. if it starts iterating over Map - expect Map to be the end result.

```
val thisIsList = for (x <- dummy; y <- x._2.keys) yield s"(${x._1}, ${y})"
println(thisIsList)  // List((1, 2), (1, 4), (6, 7))
```

In this example from the question, the *for* loop starts iterating over Map, but returns a List. Which is happening because the yield doesn't return the type which can be converted to a Map. But it can be converted to a List, so Scala does it.

```
val thisIsMap = for (x <- dummy; y <- x._2.keys) yield new Tuple2(x._1, y)
println(thisIsMap)   // Map(1 -> 4, 6 -> 7) - this is not what I want
```

In this example though, everything is happening as it should, but because the resulting Map cannot have duplicate keys, the tuple (1,2) gets overwritten by the tuple (1,4). I.e. the map contains only 2 elements.